# Javascript Variable Scope in Nested Async Waterfall Context

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, async.js, waterfall

I am trying to be a little more clear in my nested programming, but I have run up against an issue with aync.waterfall. I was wondering if anyone else had run into something similar. I have the following code which prints out the node objects correctly, but does not allow me to access the individual variables. The console output from line 17 looks like this:
Found existing node =  [ { lastName: 'Anonymous',
    emailAddress: 'myname@mydomain.com',
    formattedName: 'Henry Anonymous',
    mainAddress: '2016 Nowhere Dr\nSnogsville, TX 11121',
    firstName: 'Henry',
    _id: 0 } ] undefined

I am perplexed as to how theconsole can access the individual variables, but I cannot in my code. Any suggestions would be very welcome. Here is the code:

```
function getNode(nodeLabels, nodeProperties, getNodeCallback) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(nextCallback) {
            db.readNodesWithLabelsAndProperties(nodeLabels, nodeProperties, function (err, nodesRead) {
                nextCallback(err ? err : null
                           , (nodesRead.length < 1)
                           , (nodesRead.length < 1) ? null : nodesRead);
                });
        },

        function(createNode, existingNode, nextCallback) {
            if (createNode) {
                console.log('Creating node ...');
                db.insertNode(nodeProperties, nodeLabels, nextCallback);
            } else {
                console.log('Found existing node = ', existingNode, existingNode._id);
                nextCallback(null, existingNode);
            }
        }
    ], getNodeCallback);
}

function getPersonNode(userToGet, getPersonNodeCallback) {
    console.log(userToGet);

    getNode('Person', { firstName:     userToGet._json.firstName
                      , lastName:      userToGet._json.lastName
                      , formattedName: userToGet._json.formattedName
                      , emailAddress:  userToGet._json.emailAddress
                      , mainAddress:   userToGet._json.mainAddress
                      }
          , getPersonNodeCallback);
 }

function createRelationship(startNodeId, endNodeId, relationshipType, relationshipProperties, createRelationshipCallback) {
    console.log('Creating relationship between ', startNodeId, ' and ', endNodeId);

    async.waterfall([
        function(nextCallback) {
            db.readTypedRelationshipsOfNode(startNodeId, [relationshipType], function(err, relationshipsRead) {
                console.log('Relationships of type = ', relationshipType, ' = ', relationshipsRead);
//              nextCallback(err ? err : null
//                         , !relationshipsRead
//                         , relationshipsRead ? relationshipsRead : null);
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error trying to find existing relationship = ', err);
                    nextCallback(err, false, null);
                } else {
                    if (!relationshipsRead) {
                        console.log('Relationship does not exist, create it');
                        nextCallback( null, true, null);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Relationship already exists, do not create it');
                        nextCallback( null, false, relationshipsRead);
                    }
                }
            });
        },

        function(createRelationship, existingRelationship, nextCallback) {
            if (createRelationship) {
                db.insertRelationship(startNodeId, endNodeId, relationshipType, relationshipProperties, nextCallback);
            } else {
                nextCallback(null, existingRelationship);
            }
        }
    ], createRelationshipCallback);
}

function createAssociationRelationship(associationName, personNode, createAssociationRelationshipCallback) {
    async.waterfall([
        function(nextCallback) {
            getNode('Association', {name: associationName}, function(err, associationNode) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error getting association node = ', err);
                    nextCallback(err, null);
                } else {
                    console.log('Got association node = ', associationNode);
                    nextCallback(null, associationNode);
                }
            });
        },

        function(assocNode, nextCallback) {
            console.log('Creating relationship between ', personNode._id, ' and ', assocNode._id);
            createRelationship(personNode._id, assocNode._id, 'Is Member Of', null, function(err, normalRelationship) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error creating association relationship = ', err);
                    nextCallback(err, null);
                } else {
                    console.log('Created Is Member Of Relationship = ', normalRelationship);
                    nextCallback(null, assocNode);
                }
            });
        },

        function(assNode, nextCallback) {
            createRelationship(assNode._id, personNode._id, 'Has Member', null, function(err, reverseRelationship) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error creating association relationship = ', err);
                    nextCallback(err, null);
                } else {
                    console.log('Created Has Member Relationship = ', reverseRelationship);
                    nextCallback(null, assNode);
                }
            });
        }
    ], createAssociationRelationshipCallback);
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  if (typeof req.user != 'undefined') {
      async.waterfall([
          function(nextCallback) {
              getPersonNode(req.user, function(err, newPersonNode) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Error = ', err);
                    nextCallback(err);
                }
                console.log("Node = ", newPersonNode);
                nextCallback(null, newPersonNode);
              });
        },

        function(startNode, nextCallback) {
            req.user._json.associations.split(',').forEach(function(nameValue, index, arrayItem) {
                createAssociationRelationship(nameValue, startNode, function(err, associationRelationship) {
                    if (err)
                        console.log('Error = ', err);
                    else
                        console.log('Created relationship between ', startNode, ' and ', associationRelationship);
                });
            });
        }
    ]);
  }                                         
  res.render('index', { user: req.user });
});
```

Comment: Two keys to asynchronous programming:  (1) never try to return anything, because return values are discarded by the events that trigger the code and attempts to use a global to store a value invite timing bugs, and (2) use data in the functions where it is well defined.   So, if your console.log says data is defined in some particular function, that spot is exactly where to put the function calls to update the display or otherwise use that data.

Comment: Not quite sure which point you are trying to get across. I am not returning anything in my functions that I can see. I am taking data which I retrieved in one function and passing it to the next function via the callback which was what I thought the purpose of async.waterfall was. My question is around what is going on behind the scenes in async as far as the scope of the variables. The object prints just fine, but on the same console.log statement which prints the object, I also try to print one of the member variables and the member variables is undefined. I am not sure how that can happen.

Comment: To be a bit more clear, this call:
`console.log('Found existing node = ', existingNode, existingNode._id);`

returns the following to the console:

**Found existing node = [ { lastName: 'Anonymous', emailAddress: 'myname@mydomain.com', formattedName: 'Henry Anonymous', mainAddress: '2016 Nowhere Dr\nSnogsville, TX 11121', firstName: 'Henry', _id: 0 } ] undefined**

Comment: add `console.log(typeof(existingNode));`  on that line.  If you get back `object` then it should be able to return the fields, too, in which case checking a non-zero field might be appropriate.  A couple of weeks ago I saw a case here on SO where the type was `string` because `JSON.stringify()` was applied to the data twice before it went out.  In that case, the fix is to either eliminate the extra stringify step or to run the string through `JSON.parse()` manually to get the object back. My earlier comment was intended to be general in nature on a quick read of the question.

Comment: Also note that `console.log(something)` entered on the console always returns `undefined` as the return type of `console.log()`, after printing the information.  This is because `console.log` doesn't return anything -- it merely prints the arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js with a statemachine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26396917/node-js-with-a-statemachine)