# node.js with a statemachine

Tags: node.js, state-machine

I understand that node.js is a single thread and is a single process in the memory, I'm working on a project employing state machine and wondering how that will work in this context. I'm feeling the states will be shared across users because it's a single thread or a single process. Calling out for directions/advices.

let's say I've state A, state B, state C

Application can only transition in this sequence, A -> B -> C

Initial state is A,

user 1 requests and as a result the state machine moves to state B and then finally state C

user 2 requests, will the state machine for this new user be in state A or state C?

Comment: That totally depends on your implementation and how users request/interact with your node instance.

Comment: so if the machine is in stateC, the user2 will not find the machine in it's initial state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This article has a very interesting approach on how to deal with the FSM abstraction under an event based environment.

http://www.robert-drummond.com/2015/04/21/event-driven-programming-finite-state-machines-and-nodejs/

See also:

- https://gist.github.com/podefr/1312642
- http://machina-js.org/
- https://github.com/fschaefer/Stately.js/
- https://github.com/jakesgordon/javascript-state-machine

Answer (score 0):

If you know about Stateless C# and experience, you can use Stateless npm porting for TypeScript/JavaScript: https://www.npmjs.com/package/stateless